# Python: how to run xml file via cmd (xml.etree.ElementTree)

Tags: python, xml, raytracing

I made a simple ray tracer python program that takes xml file as input and creates a png image file.

In the python file, I used xml.etree.ElementTree as extension and implemented parser to read the xml file.

I'm trying to run the program  on cmd like:
c:\WINDOWS\system32>python3 rayTracer.py scenes/one-sphere.xml

However, it doesn't create an image.
Did I use wrong command on cmd?
(one-sphere.xml file is in the scenes file)

this is main

---

```
def main():
#parser
tree = ET.parse(sys.argv[1])
root = tree.getroot()

viewPoint = np.array([0, 0, 0]).astype(np.float)
viewDir = np.array([0, 0, -1]).astype(np.float)
viewUp = np.array([0, 1, 0]).astype(np.float)
viewProjNormal = -1 * viewDir
viewWidth = 1.0
viewHeight = 1.0
projDistance = 1.0
intensity = np.array([1, 1, 1]).astype(np.float)  # how bright the light is.

imgSize = np.array(root.findtext('image').split()).astype(np.int)

list = []
light = []

for c in root.findall('camera'):
    viewPoint = np.array(c.findtext('viewPoint').split()).astype(np.float)
    viewDir = np.array(c.findtext('viewDir').split()).astype(np.float)
    if (c.findtext('projNormal')):
        viewProjNormal = np.array(c.findtext('projNormal').split()).astype(np.float)
    viewUp = np.array(c.findtext('viewUp').split()).astype(np.float)
    if (c.findtext('projDistance')):
        projDistance = np.array(c.findtext('projDistance').split()).astype(np.float)
    viewWidth = np.array(c.findtext('viewWidth').split()).astype(np.float)
    viewHeight = np.array(c.findtext('viewHeight').split()).astype(np.float)

view = View(viewPoint, viewDir, viewUp, viewProjNormal, viewWidth, viewHeight, projDistance, intensity)

for c in root.findall('surface'):
    type_c = c.get('type')
    if type_c == 'Sphere':
        center_c = np.array(c.findtext('center').split()).astype(np.float)
        radius_c = np.array(c.findtext('radius')).astype(np.float)
        ref = ''
        for child in c:
            if child.tag == 'shader':
                ref = child.get('ref')
        for d in root.findall('shader'):
            if d.get('name') == ref:
                diffuse_d = np.array(d.findtext('diffuseColor').split()).astype(np.float)
                type_d = d.get('type')

for c in root.findall('light'):
    position_c = np.array(c.findtext('position').split()).astype(np.float)
    intensity_c = np.array(c.findtext('intensity').split()).astype(np.float)
    light.append(Light(position_c, intensity_c))

# Create an empty image
channels = 3
img = np.zeros((imgSize[1], imgSize[0], channels), dtype=np.uint8)
img[:, :] = 0


pixel_x = view.viewWidth / imgSize[0]
pixel_y = view.viewHeight / imgSize[1]

w = view.viewDir
u = np.cross(w, view.viewUp)
v = np.cross(w, u)


w_unit = w / np.sqrt(np.sum(w * w))
u_unit = u / np.sqrt(np.sum(u * u))
v_unit = v / np.sqrt(np.sum(v * v))

start = w_unit * view.projDistance - u_unit * pixel_x * ((imgSize[0]/2) + 1/2) - v_unit * pixel_y * ((imgSize[1]/2) + 1/2)


for x in np.arange(imgSize[0]):
    for y in np.arange(imgSize[1]):
        ray = start + u_unit * x * pixel_x + pixel_y * y * v_unit
        tmp = raytrace(list, ray, view.viewPoint)
        img[y][x] = shade(tmp[0], ray, view, list, tmp[1], light)

rawimg = Image.fromarray(img, 'RGB')
rawimg.save(sys.argv[1] + '.png')

if __name__ == "__main__":
 main()
```

Comment: Please post attempted code of `rayTracer.py` for [mcve].

Comment: @Parfait Thank you for replying! I added main() part to the post. The first two lines are the parser and there is an image creation part below.

Comment: There are no `import` statements in the code. The indentation does not look right. And you haven't shown us what's in one-sphere.xml.

Comment: Did you get any errors? Do you have some prints in the code that would let you know how far you got? I assume you are creating an output file. Print its absolute path (`print(os.path.abspath("whatever it is"))` to make sure you have the output directory right. Write a very simple test script that just opens and writes junk to a file. See if that works and then scale up to your script from there.